# Getting message from kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a properties file for JDBC Kafka connect. Where the `topic.prefix=test-mysql-jdbc-`

As per my knowledge when we run the standalone connector -

`$ /usr/bin/connect-standalone /etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties/etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-quickstart-mysql.properties`

A topic is created named `test-mysql-jdbc-`

Now I create the consumer

`$ /usr/bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer -–topic test-mysql-jdbc-students --zookeeper localhost:2181 --from-beginning`

and I get JSON data successfully..

Now What I did is I deleted the kafka logs(which deleted all the topics) but when I am repeating the same process, The topic with same name is created but I am not getting any data in the consumer. If I change the `topic.prefix` to something new. I get the data again. Please Explain

Answer (score 0):

> and I get JSON data successfully

You're actually getting deserialized Avro (shown as JSON)

> I deleted the kafka logs(which deleted all the topics)

Sounds like you didn't delete any Zookeeper data, so the topic metadata still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be two scenarios.

1. When you're deleting Kafka logs you are erasing control and server
   logs not data logs.
2. Another thing, deleting kafka logs will not
   really delete Kafka topic. You have to use `./kafka-topics.sh
   --zookeeper <IP>:<port> --delete --topic <topic_name>` along with `delete.topic.enable=true` in server.properties.

Verify using `--describe` option. You might see the partition leaders assigned to -1 or topic marked for deletion.

The faulty topic metadata will not allow proper offset management and hinder topic consumption.